# Python logic isn't yielding the correct answer and I'm having difficulty with developing the context

Tags: python-3.x

Values including height = 10, number = 2, and bounciness = 6 should come to 25.6 feet, but I'm getting 23.2 feet. Can someone help me understand where my logic is screwed up please?

```
import math

# User inputs are set up

height = int(input("Enter the height of the ball: "))
number = int(input("Enter the number of bounces of the ball: "))
bounciness = int(input("Enter the height for each successive bounce: "))

count = 0

# Calculation

for count in range(bounciness):
    count = (height * bounciness)/100
    distance = height + count
    bounceSum = number * bounciness
    total = count + distance + bounceSum

# Results

print("The ball has traveled a total distance of", total, "feet.")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the calculation in the for loop, this is what happens in the first iterations (and ones after that too):-

`count` = 10*6/100 = 0.6
`distance` = 10 + 0.6 = 10.6 (*count is 0.6 here because of the line above*)
`bounceSum` = 2*12 = 12
`total` = 0.6 + 10.6 + 12 = 23.2

The problem with the logic in your code is the variable `count`. There are 3 different definitions of it and they keep overwriting the other:

1. `count` = 0 above the for loop
2. `count` which ranges from 0 to bounciness-1
3. `count` = (height*bounciness)/100

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it...

```
import math

# User inputs are set up

height = int(input("Hello, please enter the height of the ball: "))
number = int(input("Next, enter the number of bounces of the ball: "))
bounciness = int(input("Now enter the height for each successive bounce: "))

index = 0

# Calculation

for index in range(bounciness):
    index = bounciness * 0.6
    distance = height + (bounciness * number)
    total = index + distance

# Results

print("The ball has traveled a total distance of", total, "feet.")

print("Good bye")
```